# Blocking an IP range on Windows server 2008

Tags: security, windows-server-2008, ip, windows-firewall

How to define a rule in Windows server 2008 firewall to be applied to an IP range. For example blocking IPs which start with 202 I mean all IPs which meet 202.*.*.*

There are two options when creating a new rule:

1. This IP address or subset:
2. This IP address range:

How should I define such a wide range ?

Comment: That is the range between 202.0.0.0 to 202.255.255.255. I assume that you mean IPv4.

Comment: I'd first ask the question, "why are you blocking all those IPs in the first place?"  A blanket answer wouldn't fit here, nor would it be beneficial to you in the long term.

Comment: Yes I mean IP v4. I was wondering if this wide range has a negative performance issue or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range begins at `202.0.0.0` and ends at `202.255.255.255`. You can also represent it as `202.0.0.0/8`.

### Why `/8`?

An IPv4 address is a 32-digit binary number that has been conveniently divided into 4 groups. The address `202.0.0.0` expressed in binary is

```
11001010 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

In this context `/8` means "match the first 8 binary digits", or any address that begins with `202.`.

Read all about it at the Wikipedia article for [Classless Inter-Domain Routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).

Comment: Why `202.0.0.0/8` ? What does 8 mean here ?

Comment: @Xaqron I updated my answer to address your question.